# How to save inserted TableView Cells in the UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Ive been attempting to save cells that are added into a TableView once the app is closed. Whenever the app is reloaded or reopened the added cells are deleted.

This is my function to insert a cell when a button is tapped:

```
func insertMessageInRow() {

    messages.append(MessageTextField.text!)

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: messages.count - 1, section: 0)
    UserDefaults.standard.didChangeValue(forKey: "Save")
    SavedMessages.beginUpdates()
    SavedMessages.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    SavedMessages.endUpdates()

    MessageTextField.text = ""
    view.endEditing(true)

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(messages, forKey: "Save")

}
```

This is my code or the TableView to insert the cell and change the label:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let defualts = UserDefaults.standard
    let stingArray = defualts.stringArray(forKey: "Save") ?? [String]()

    let message = stingArray[indexPath.row]

    let cell = SavedMessages.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.MessageLable.text = message

    return cell
}
```

I can't seem to get the table to save anything when the app is closed. I've looked around the internet for days now on how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't store app data in UserDefaults.

Comment: @rmaddy I’m attempting to learn Swift. What would you suggest?

Comment: Depends on how much data you will have. If not much, write the data to a file. If a lot of data, use a database (Core Data).

Comment: @rmaddy thanks! I’ll browse around to learn about that.

Comment: You should definitely have a proper data layer, like CoreData or Realm. UserDefaults should be only used for simple user preferences!